# Table build with flex with sticky row and columns: style bnot applied and sticky clumns disapears

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sticky

I am trying to build a table using flexbox. The code structure is:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.sticky-row,
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.sticky-row {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky-cell {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: aqua;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky-row">
    <div class="sticky-cell">sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky-cell">sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky-cell">sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky-cell">sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky-cell">sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
    <div>not sticky-cell</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

([CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-waterfall-rf2dem?file=/index.html))

My issues are:

- the style is not applied to cells not visible before the horizontal scroll
- the sticky column disappears when I scroll too far

I could probably make it work with `<table>` but it would be much easier to integrate in my code with flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test you can put `width: fit-content;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.sticky-row,
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: fit-content; <-- here
}

.sticky-row {
  position: sticky; 
  background-color: aqua;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky-cell {
  position: sticky;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0;
}

.sticky-row.sticky-cell {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

([code block](https://codesandbox.io/embed/boring-field-xpdmq0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark))